# Using a partial view to represent a table row

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

I am trying to use a partial view to represent rows of a table in my project. I currently have

```
 <table> 
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th >
                Column 1
            </th>
            <th >
                 Column 2
            </th>
            <th >
                 Column 3
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         @foreach(var item in Model.Items)
         {
         @Html.Action("ItemCalculatedView", new { Id = item.Id}) 
         }
     </tbody>
     </table>
```

In my partial view I have this

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveStuff", "Whatever",
    new { id = @Model.Id }, new AjaxOptions()
    {
        HttpMethod = "Post",
        OnSuccess = "Success"
    }))
   {
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    <tr>
       <td>
          @Html.Label("Col1", Model.Col1)
       </td>
       <td>
          @Html.TextBox("Number", Model.Number)
       </td>
       <td>
          <input type="submit" id='submit-@Model.Id'/>
       </td>
     </tr>           
     }
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put a form inside a table *cell*, but you can't have the form inside a *tbody* element, or spanning multiple columns.  So there are three options:

1. Use a CSS layout instead of a table, or use divs with [CSS display set to "table"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display).   ([for example](http://jsfiddle.net/yZMxE/1/))
2. Put the entire form (TextBox and Submit) inside a `td`
3. Put another table inside the `td` element

I'd recommend #1 -- use a CSS layout to construct the table, since it's difficult to style `table` tags:

**Main**

```
<div class="table"> 
    <div class="header-row">
        <div class="header-cell">Column 1</th>
        <div class="header-cell">Column 2</th>
        <div class="header-cell">Column 3</th>
    </div>

     @foreach(var item in Model.Items)
     {
         @Html.Action("ItemCalculatedView", new { Id = item.Id}) 
     }
</div>
```

**Partial**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
  actionName: "SaveStuff", 
  controllerName: "Whatever",
  routeValues: new { id = @Model.Id }, 
  ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions
  {
      HttpMethod = "Post",
      OnSuccess = "Success"
  },
  htmlAttributes: new { @class = "row" }
 ))
 {
   <div class="cell">
       @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
   </div>
   <div class="cell">
      @Html.Label("Col1", Model.Col1)
   </div>
   <div class="cell">
      @Html.TextBox("Number", Model.Number)
   </div>
   <div class="cell">
      <input type="submit" id='submit-@Model.Id'/>
   </div>
 }
```

**CSS**

```
.table { display: table; }
.header-row, row { display: table-row; }
.header-cell, cell { display: table-cell; }
```

Comment: Awesome, my design skills just went up :)

Comment: @GatesReign caveat on using `display: table`:  IE7 and earlier doesn't support it: http://caniuse.com/css-table

Comment: My form (Ajax.BeginForm) seems to breaks the table layout. The table does work when their is no form element in the layout, but tries to force table rows in the first column of the table header. eg<table>
  <form><tr><td>
    content
  </td></tr></form>
</table>

Comment: @GatesReign it's possible to get the layout right -- maybe set the *form* itself to have "class=row".  See updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yZMxE/1/

Comment: Two issues, first, as dbaseman mentions.. IE7 doesn't support css tables, and the second is that this is not semantically correct and will not display correctly for screen readers and what not.  I would strongly discourage using css tables for tabular data.

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues here.  First, as dbaseman mentions, you can't place forms within the structure of a table and have it be legal HTML.  It may work, or it might not, and even if it does work, you can't guarantee it will continue to work.

I would instead wrap your table in the form, and then on the post figure out which button was pressed based on its value and/or index.

I would strongly advise against using css tables for tabular data.  It's just not semantically correct.

Another possible solution is, instead of using the Ajax.BeginForm, instead use jQuery $.ajax and then you can select a row of data in javascript to post to the server.